# Where can i use "on high" with "disappointment"?

Tags: word-usage

For example: "disappointment level on high". Like we use "FOMO on high", so the same way can we write this?

Comment: Your question is impossible to understand.

Comment: This *is* hard to understand.  You have lots of typos, spelling mistakes and punctuation mistakes.  However I think the answer is simple, except in very casual speech, both "disappointment level on high" and "FOMO on high" are not expressions used in English.  (I can find one example of "FOMO on high", in a casual Instagram comment by a Kardashian.

Comment: Presumably _on high_ is used in the sense _on a high setting_ rather than _in in a high position_.

Comment: @JamesK - apparently it means 'Fear Of Missing Out'.

Answer (score 2):

"FOMO on high" is very very casual and probably not understandable except in context.

"Disappointment level on high" is very very casual, and probably not understandable.

Don't use either expression. (unless you are a vapid "valley girl" writing Instagram comments)

Comment: +1 for 'vapid'.